# Is it possible to poll CANOpen variables through SDO, and if so, how?

Tags: canopen

I have set up a CANOpen network consisting of 3 engines, each having their own CANOpen slave. I have a Hilscher CifX board acting as CANOpen master.

I have achieved proper engine command by reading and writing RPDO and TPDO directly into the process memory of the Hilscher board.

Now, I tried to set up the network through Sycon.NET (the Hilscher configuration tool) to map additional variables to the PDO, but the variables I want to capture don't appear in the list. I figure this is because the EDS metions `PDO Mapping = 0` for these variables.

I would like to read the values of these variables every 20ms or so. Can I do this by polling the device through SDOs? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do an SDO Upload on the object.

The message should look something like this(Object index: 0x1234, Sub index: 0x01):

Id: 0x680 + NodeId, DLC: 8, Data: 0x40 0x34 0x12 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00

You can find further info on SDO in CiA DS301.

Comment: @M.Neubauer: Thank you. I looked into the DS301 and could map your example to the mesage structure of the "Initiate SDO Upload" protocol. I see that the "expedited transfer" bit is part of the response from the slave (in my case). Does it mean that the slave gets to choose the transfer mode in this case? Is there a guarantee that, since the data is never longer than 4 bytes, the slave will always choose to use expedited transfer?

Comment: Yes, it´s up to the slave to decide the transfer mode. I think most implementations will do an expedited transfer. But it´s possible to transfer less than 4 bytes via a segmented upload. So there is no guarantee.